# Accessing the container file system from host non root

Tags: docker

How do I access a folder on the Container from host.

1. I start a container, and lets say I want to see on host the contents of the container's /home.
2. Without being root and going to the docker overlay file system to see what is there. But of course I am in group docker and can ask docker to make the neccessary actions.
3. What if I wish to mount the /home of the container to /test on the host?
4. I want to avoid mounting a host path into the container and copying from there since I dont want to allow the container to write to host, but the host will copy the content by himself.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer two questions:

2)  To see the contents of a directory inside the container, use docker exec command.

Here is an example of how to:

```
# docker run -it --rm --name test_con ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

You can then open a new terminal session and run the command.

```
# docker exec test_con  ls /home
```

Replace `test_con` with the name or ID of your container and `ls /home` with any command you want to be executed on the container without attaching to its console.

3) You can use `docker cp` command to copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem. Using above container as an example, you’ll run a command like this:

```
# docker cp test_con:/home /test
```

Where `/test` is a directory on the host system. It will be automatically created if it doesn't exist.

Your question 2 and 4 seem to be duplicate of the other two.